# Visual Studio Interactive Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Whilst asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151967/import-project-to-immediate) question, I created a new tag: [c#-interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-interactive) - in the same vein as the existing [f#-interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23-interactive).

In the efforts to keep the tags "correct", I wanted to bring this up here for discussion.

In my view, there are a couple of different tag structures that could be used:

1. Use separate tags for `C#` and `F#` Interactive - as is currently in place
2. Merge the two tags to [visual-studio-interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-interactive) and rely on additional language tags to indicate the required language (if relevant).
3. Merge both these tags into an existing tag (such as [read-eval-print-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/read-eval-print-loop))

I think 3 might be too ambiguous, since questioners may not know to look for that specific tag.

In my opinion, option 2 may be the best solution.

Comment: This is brand new for C#, and implemented very differently, no doubt with a bucket-load of agile bugs.  Keeping it [c#-interactive] would be wise.